I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
As many users, I'm having problems with the bluetooth.
I'm using Linux 6.8.0-45-generic on x86_64 #45-Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, just freshly installed.
When I go on Settings -> Bluetooth and click the toggle to enable, it instantly disables itself.
My laptop is just bought and you can see the full specs here
I tried to follow most of the steps in

I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1859592

None solved the problem.
I cannot remove the battery from my laptop, so I tried the disable/enable on the bios trick but did not help.
The main error message reported is:

Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110

sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.511496] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.511532] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.511535] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.511548] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.511553] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.511561] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.437283] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.437291] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.437307] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.675379] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110

But differently from many other people who reported the error, when I check the status of bluetooth.service it says active:
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-09-17 13:17:46 BST; 21min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 949 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 37564)
     Memory: 2.8M (peak: 3.1M)
        CPU: 51ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─949 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix bluetoothd[949]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix systemd[1]: Starting bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service...
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix (uetoothd)[949]: bluetooth.service: ConfigurationDirectory 'bluetooth' already exists but the mode is different. (>
Sep 17 13:17:46 matrix systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.

Does anyone have any tips of what could I try/check?

Edited: Adding lsusb output as requested.
$ lsusb; sudo dmesg| grep -i firm
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3585 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL3523 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2b7e:c858 Kingcome FHD WebCam
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

It's an internal blutooth not a usb one... but added in case I'm missing something.

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg| grep -i firm

Added it. Although it's an internal bluetooth not a USB one, so I don't think this output is meaningful.

That device isn't in the kernel source code yet, in terminal check mokutil --sb as Secure Boot needs to be disabled, then
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.8
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
Reboot

Good step forward, but I have still problems. My panasonic soundbar connects, but then it doesn't display as output (I tried pavucontrol too). My Galaxy buds don't appear at all. Will I have to keep the laptop in disabled Secure Boot forever? If I enable it the bluetooth won't toggle on again.

This code should be in the 6.10 kernel and it will be available before January in Ubuntu repos then Secure Boot can be enabled with 6.10. Not sure why the soundbar wouldn't show as a sound output device. I think Ubuntu uses pipewire and not pulseaudio now

Thanks, I'll approve the answer and wait until 6.10 :-)
